# Twig: Looping over array of objects

Tags: php, twig

I was wondering if is there any way to loop to such a struct with Twig:

```
{%
  set languages = [
    {"english": "en"},
    {"spanish": "es"},
    {"italian": "it"},
    {"german": "de"},
    {"french": "fr"},
    {"portuguese": "pt"},
  ]
%}

{% for value in languages %}
  Language: {{value.??}} - Locale: {{value.??}}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't like to split object in a "key value" pair just to have properties named... any way to achieve this?

In the meanwhile I modified the struct as follows to use a simple key value looping:

```
{%
  set languages = {
    "english": "en",
    "spanish": "es",
    "italian": "it",
    "german": "de",
    "french": "fr",
    "portuguese": "pt"
  }
%}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop over the object too, using the same key/value pair:

```
{%
  set languages = [
    {"english": "en"},
    {"spanish": "es"},
    {"italian": "it"},
    {"german": "de"},
    {"french": "fr"},
    {"portuguese": "pt"},
  ]
%}

{% for value in languages %}
  {% for k, v in value %}
    Language: {{k}} - Locale: {{v}} <br />
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{# output:
  Language: english - Locale: en
  Language: spanish - Locale: es
  Language: italian - Locale: it
  Language: german - Locale: de
  Language: french - Locale: fr
  Language: portuguese - Locale: pt 
#}
```

Comment: Nice! However I changed the struct to a simple dictionary to avoid the overhead. thanks damien

Comment: Can the downvoter explain his -1? This is a clean solution, and perfectly valid in Twig

Answer (score 1):

I have some very dirty, but working solution:

```
{% for value in languages|keys %}
    Language: {{ languages[value]|keys|first }} - Locale: {{ languages[value]|first }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what a dirty trick, it works but damien has a better solution! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm ashamed I've posted something like this... :<

Comment: ahaha, just don't: sometimes quircks are needed to get to the end of the day. fortunately my brain got back working again and came out with a better solution too :)